# use data-iscroll within a data-role="collapsible"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a collapsible content that its list of items

(ul data-role="listview")

will have scrolling ability using data-iscroll.

Comment: Great. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are expecting. Hope so this might help.

```
 <ul style="padding: 10px;width: 300px;"> 
    <li style="background: #e2ffff;padding: 5px;font-weight: bold;" id="first">Title1
        <ul style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; background-color: rgb(238, 34, 255); padding: 10px; display: none; max-height: 60px; overflow-y: auto;" id="content">
             <li>This is sample test This is sample test This is sample test This is sample test This is sample test This is sample test This is sample test This is sample test This is sample test This is sample test
             </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script>

    $("#first").click(function(){
    $("#content").slideToggle(1000);

    });
    </script>
```

Thanks and Regards.